# How do I test localization in a winforms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, testing, localization

Is there a way to test different languages in a Windows application without changing the localization of the OS or adding code to the application to forcibly change the current culture?

Perhaps some type of a launcher that will launch the application with a specified culture?

Comment: What I was actually working on was a plugin for another application.  It turns out the other application has it's own method of setting the language, and thus the answers below did not work for me.  However I will mark Gulzar's solution as correct because it was the correct answer for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/apploc.mspx) Utility for XP, which can also be installed on [vista](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/26/workaround-to-install-microsoft-applocale-utility-in-windows-vista/).

AppLocale automatically detects language for non-Unicode program and simulates a corresponding system locale for code-page to/from Unicode conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch your application with the [main thread set to an specified culture](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/20/quickly-testing-code-under-different-cultures.aspx).